# requests declines certificate

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I can access `https://siscourses.ethz.ch/python_dbiol/data/logistic_data.txt` with `curl` or within google chrome without any complaints about the certificate.

If I run

```
import requests
request.get("https://siscourses.ethz.ch/python_dbiol/data/logistic_data.txt")
```

I get

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:749)

What is going wrong here ? I could disable certificate validation, but would prefer to understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"siscourses.ethz.ch" use SSL certificate from Let’s Encrypt, but isn't configurated to send complete certificate chain, [intermediates certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) missed. It will work for chrome (on your computer) because you have successfully visited other websites using Let’s Encrypt, chrome cached the missing intermediates.

you could check this with [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=siscourses.ethz.ch), or:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect siscourses.ethz.ch:443
```

Comment: Thanks. I configured nginx to use `fullchamin.pem` instead of `cert.pem` and now it works.

Comment: I try to be a sys admin ;)